# How to create an if statement which check if text field empty?

Tags: ios, if-statement, uitextfield

I have three text fields, lets name them:

1. textField1.
2. textField2
3. textField3

I want to write an if statement if the value (integer) of textField1 is changed to set textField2 and textField3 to equal 0 if they have no number entered within them.

Likewise with textField2 to change textField1 and textField3, etc.

I have tried to check if

```
 textField2 = nil;
    if textField2 = @""
```

Neither work!

How do I do so?

Comment: clarify your question, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to check if a text field has any text is to do:

```
if (textField2.text.length == 0) {
    // no text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `textField.text` property to check the text in textField. You can use

```
if ([textField1.text length] == 0)
```

to check textfield is empty or not

Comment: The 2nd approach is best since `textField.text` can be `nil`. So the 1st check would fail in such a case.